# Electron Energy Approximation for Multielectron Atoms

Tags: atomic-physics, approximations

**Given the question:** lithium ($Z = 3$) has two electrons in $1s$ and one in $2s$. Estimate the energy of the third electron when it is raised to $3d$.

Since the $3d$ orbital is quite far away from the $2s$ I use a $Z_{eff} \approx 1$. Thus, treating the nucleus and the two electrons with $+e$ charge (essentially like a hydrogen atom). Since $3d$ orbital is in the third energy shell, I can approximate the orbital's energy as

$$E = \frac{-13.6eV}{n^2} = -1.512eV$$

The solution comes to the same answer, however, they claim that "its energy should be just the hydrogenic energy $\frac{-E}{Z^2} = -1.512 eV$". I don't understand why $Z$ should be divided in this approximation. Does this approach make any sense?